# Wage arithmetic returns wrong answer

Tags: java

```
public double totalWages(double hours, double rate)
  {
    double wages;
    if (hours <= 40){
        wages = hours * rate;
    }
    else {
        wages = ((hours * rate) + ((hours - 40) * (1.5 * rate)));
    }
    return wages;
 }
```

Basically, if a person works overtime hours (above 40 hours), their rate will be 1.5 times their original rate for the overtime hours, so if someone works 45 hours for 12.5) dollars per hour, they would earn $593.75.

My first case is working (hours <= 40), but the second case seems to be returning the wrong answer for the example above (it is returning $656.25). Is there something wrong with my operators, or maybe the way I wrote the equation according to Java syntax?

Comment: If doing overtime, the wages should be `40 hours * base rate + extra hours * base rate * 1.5`, but that's not what you have. (Or `all hours * base rate + extra hours * base rate * 0.5`, I suppose.)

Answer (score 1):

The Java is okay (even though I am afraid of using floating points for monetary amounts), but the math is off.

You are applying the normal rate for *all* hours (not just the first 40), and then the overtime rate for the overtime hours on top of that.